# ORA-00905: missing keyword in SQL PLus

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I am getting an ORA-00905: missing keyword error when running in the following procedure using the SQLPLUS command line. Strangely it compiles and works when I run it in via an SQL window in PL/SQL developer, unfortunately I need it to work via the command line as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRO_INSERT_ALERT_END_DATE IS



CURSOR cur_InsertEndDate IS

    SELECT cli_per_id,
           date_ended,
           date_started,
           alertid
    FROM   CP_END_ALERT;

BEGIN



FOR rec_cur_InsertEndDate IN cur_InsertEndDate
LOOP

    BEGIN

        UPDATE vwe_alert_table
        SET    alert_inactive_on = rec_cur_InsertEndDate.date_ended,
               alert_inac_reason = 'Deregistered'
        WHERE  vwe_alert_table.art_id = rec_cur_InsertEndDate.alertid AND
               vwe_alert_table.art_per_id = rec_cur_InsertEndDate.cli_per_id AND
               vwe_alert_table.art_alerted_on = rec_cur_InsertEndDate.date_started AND
               vwe_alert_table.art_alert = 'AL02';


        COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN

            dbms_output.put_line('Error updating record ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 250));
            ROLLBACK;

    END;
   END LOOP;
END PRO_INSERT_ALERT_END_DATE;
```

Any advice would be most welcome

Comment: that procedure isn't valid and won't compile anywhere as you have an extra `END;` in there before the `END LOOP;` if you remove it, does it work? if not what line is it complaining about?

Comment: The extra end was an error on my part, I have removed it and am still getting the same ORA-00905: missing keyword error  error at line 1, many thanks for looking at this btw.

Comment: to be clear, this is showing the error on the CREATE line (it should show a * at the error position)? (can you paste the exact output here instead of the proc definition). the create or replace line you've put here is OK. i'd expect that error on `CREATE OR REPLACE` if you'd mis-spelled REPLACE for example. eg `CREATE OR REPACE PROCEDURE PRO_INSERT_ALERT_END_DATE IS
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Comment: It is probabky not very illuminating but this is the output I am getting:

Comment: *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: eliminate the empty lines or prefix them with line comment delimiters (`--`).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to the blank lines in the script. Tell SqlPlus to ignore them

```
 set sqlblanklines on
```